# solve $|x-6|>|x^2-5x+9|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

> solve $|x-6|>|x^2-5x+9|,\ \ x\in \mathbb{R}$

I have done $4$ cases.

$1.)\ x-6>x^2-5x+9\ \ ,\implies  x\in \emptyset \\
2.)\ x-6<x^2-5x+9\ \ ,\implies x\in \mathbb{R} \\
3.)\  -(x-6)>x^2-5x+9\ ,\implies 1<x<3\\
4.)\  (x-6)>-(x^2-5x+9),\ \implies x>3\cup x<1 $

I am confused on how I proceed.

Or if their is any other short way than making $4$ cases than I would like to know.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to note the inequality is equivalent to
$$(x-6)^2>(x^2-5x+9)^2\iff -(x-1)(x-3)(x^2-6x+15)>0$$
The quadratic is always positive, so this is the same as $(x-1)(x-3)<0$ which means $x\in (1,3)$.

Comment: How do you prove that displayed equivalence? It's not immediately obvious, at least to me.

Comment: @A.P. Which part of $|x|>|y| \iff x^2>y^2 \iff (x+y)(x-y)>0$ ?  I assume factoring the quadratic is not worrisome.

Comment: It isn't worrisome at all, but it wasn't clear that that's what you did...

Comment: @A.P. Just wanted to show the OP a way without cases. Not intended as a step by step working, I have found working the details helps people internalise the solution better.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $x^2-5x+9=\dfrac{(2x-5)^2+11}4\ge\dfrac{11}4>0\forall $ real $x$

So, $|x^2-5x+9|=+(x^2-5x+9)\forall $ real $x$

So, the problem reduces to two cases for $|x-6|$

Also, $|x-6|>\dfrac{11}4\implies \pm(x-6)>\dfrac{11}4$

Answer (score 2):

It usually helps to draw a [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+-+5x+%2B9+and+%7Cx-6%7C) of the functions involved.

First of all, note that the discriminant of the parabola $P: x^2 - 5x + 9 = 0$ is $5^2 - 4\cdot9 < 0$, thus $x^2 - 5x + 9$ is always positive. This means that you are looking for the points $x \in \Bbb{R}$ for which the graph of $|x-6|$ lies above $P$.

Then observe that the line $\ell: x - 6 = 0$ intersects $P$ if and only if $x^2 - 5x + 9 = x - 6$, i.e. if and only if
$$
x^2 - 6x + 15 = 0
$$
which again is a quadratic equation with negative discriminant, thus $\ell$ lies below $P$, i.e. $|x-6|$ lies below $P$ for every $x \geq 6$.

On the other hand, the line $r: 6-x = 0$ intersects $P$ in two points because
$$
x^2 - 4x + 3 = 0
$$
has roots $x = 1$ and $x = 3$. This means that $r$, and thus the graph of $|x - 6|$ lies above $P$ precisely for $1 < x < 3$.

**Note:** Here I have tacitly used the fact that $P$ will always lie above any given line for $x$ large or small enough.

---

**TL;DR:** When confronted with absolute values do not blindly write down all the possible cases. Usually it pays to first try to figure out when the arguments of the absolute values are positive. Also it helps to visualise things from a geometric point of view, especially when low-degree polynomial functions are involved.